# Mousehover on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi i have created a confirm popup method by using

```
{
  if (confirm ("Are you Mad!") == true) {
    alert("Good");
    prompt
  }
  else {
    alert("Yes you are MAD!");
  }
}
```

now i want to implement mouse-hover on the buttons hat when i point on Ok it should be cancel and whenever i point the "ok" and "cancel" should revert.Thank you

Comment: Please format the source code you are trying to provide and explain the problem you are having along with what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Well, you cannot customize the browser alert and popup boxes. That's the hard truth.

Comment: You cannot customize the prompt. You can instead create your own popup which will serve you better

Comment: when did "this is impossible" become the same thing as "it's unclear what you're asking?" ..this question is perfectly clear. there's no reason for 5 downvotes either. "you can't do that" is a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate the buttons on the native prompt/alert/confirm dialogues but you can create your own. Here's some quick code using "vanilla" JS but it can be done a lot easier with [jquery](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or any other front end framework.

```js
// Helper function to sort of emulate the confirm box
const ask = question => {
  let modal = document.createElement("div");
  let ok = document.createElement("button");
  let cancel = document.createElement("button");
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  let header = document.createElement("div");
  header.style.background = "#7c7c7c";
  modal.style.position = "absolute";
  modal.style.right = "0";
  modal.style.left = "0";
  modal.style.margin = "15px auto 0 auto";
  modal.style.width = "350px";
  modal.style.zIndex = "999999999";
  modal.style.border = "1px solid #a5a5a5";
  modal.style.background = "#bababa";
  modal.style.padding = "3px";
  ok.style.float = "right";
  cancel.style.float = "right";
  header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Confirm"));
  cancel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cancel"));
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(question));
  ok.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ok"));
  modal.appendChild(header);
  modal.appendChild(div);
  modal.appendChild(cancel);
  modal.appendChild(ok);
  document.body.appendChild(modal);
  return {
    ok: ok,
    cancel: cancel,
    close: ()=>modal.parentNode.removeChild(modal)
  };
};

// Create a modal asking if the user loves to fart
let modal = ask("do u <3 2 fart?");

// If the user indicates that they do indeed <3 2 fart
// close the modal and log a message to the console
modal.ok.onclick = ()=>{
  modal.close();
  console.log("u <3 2 fart");
};

// If the user indicates that they do not <3 2 fart
// close the modal and log a message to the console
modal.cancel.onclick = ()=>{
  modal.close();
  console.log("u not <3 2 fart");
};

// If the  user mouses over the ok button, 
// change the text
modal.ok.onmouseover = ()=>
  modal.ok.innerHTML = "&hearts;";
  
// If the  user removes mouse from ok button
// restore the text
modal.ok.onmouseout = ()=>
  modal.ok.innerHTML = "Ok";

// If the  user mouses over the cancel button, 
// change the text
modal.cancel.onmouseover = ()=>
  modal.cancel.innerHTML = "!&hearts;";
  
// If the  user removes mouse from cancel button
// restore the text
modal.cancel.onmouseout = ()=>
  modal.cancel.innerHTML = "Cancel";
```

lol

Comment: Hi thank you but unable to run on my tool why so?

Comment: @ShashiSharma I don't know. I'm just giving you an example, not writing production code. if you want to use this exact code post it as a new question. please put the checkmark back as I have answered this question. feel free to ask a new one if you have a new problem.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much it was helpful